# Appscript to pull data from one sheet and copy to another sheet on the same spreadsheet based on condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to expand one of Google's simple mail merge tutorials into something that can improve a workflow at my work. Here's my set up.  I have a Google Form set up for teachers to fill out their sub plan.  In the response spreadsheet, I have a second sheet containing information for all of my teachers (i.e. their class schedules).

I want it so that when a teacher fills out the form, the appscript automatically populates cells with their schedule based on their names.  I know that I can do a VLOOKUP and use a copyDown formula, but the problem is that VLOOKUP takes too long and my mailmerge that is set to send on form submit and is not able to retrieve data quick enough.

Maybe someone can correct me, but my hope was that by writing a function that actually populates automatically(instead of VLOOKUP that seems to take longer) prior to the send mail function, this would resolve the issue.

I know it's not much, but below is what I have started and the rest is beyond me.

```
function insertData() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 //gets the information from sheet1
  var firstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
  var firstRange = firstSheet.getRange(2,2, firstSheet.getMaxRows()-1, 24);

  object1 = getRowsData(firstSheet, firstRange);
  //gets the information from sheet2
  var secondSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Teachers");
  var secondRange = secondSheet.getRange(2, 1, secondSheet.getMaxRows()-1, 9);

  object2 = getRowsData(secondSheet, secondRange);

  for(var i = 0; i < object1.length; ++i){
    for(var j = 0; j < object2.length; ++j){


    }
    }
}
```

Here is the link to my spreadsheet with three examples filled from a form.  I need it to automatically fill the rest of the cells based on the name "This sub plan is for" using the "Teachers" sheet.

```
[Spreadsheet][1]
```

I'd appreciate any insight.